# How to multiply a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.0 query returning results in a way similar to this:

```
item;qty
AAAA;2
EEEE;3
```

What I would like is to transform that into:

```
AAAA
AAAA
EEEE
EEEE
EEEE
```

Is there any way I can do that on simple, i.e., without stored procedures, functions, etc?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Beyond that ... do you mean to say you've crammed `item` and `qty` into one column as text? If so - don't do that. Problem half way solved.

Comment: What will you use the duplicated values for? There might be a less-awkward solution to the ultimate problem...

Comment: I assume you're using some sort of presentational layer after fetching the data; giving the effect of "multiplying" rows like that in the front end could make a lot more sense, as @djacobson says tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: @djacobson Sorry for the late answer. item is a string column and qty an integer column. Think of it as a list of items in a purchase order. qty is an attribute indicating the number of equal items. Yes, the final target is to display this in a sort of presentational layer, but it's quite limited, so if possible I will prefer a solution in SQL. In the end, the solution provided by Luther_Blissett worked like a charm. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function 'generate_series' which can be used to generate a table of values. These can be used to repeat a column via joining:

```
select item 
from data,generate_series(0,1000) 
where generate_series<qty order by item;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x(item text, qty int);

INSERT INTO x VALUES
 ('AAAA',2)
,('EEEE',3)
,('IIII',4);

SELECT regexp_split_to_table(rtrim(repeat(item||'~#~',qty),'~#~'),'~#~') AS item
FROM   x;
```

Produces exactly the requested result.

- In my tests it performs faster by an order of magnitude than the solution with `generate_series()`.
- Additional bonus: works with *any* number of `qty`.
- Weakness: you need a delimiter-string not contained in any `item`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  myTable.item
FROM
  myTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS counter UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS multiplier
    ON multiplier.counter <= myTable.qty
```

Increase the number of UNIONS based on your Maximum value in `qty`

But I'd also follow @djacobson's advice : explain why you want to do this, as the may be a completely different approach altogether.  Doing this feels, ummm, odd...

Comment: *shudders at the thought using this with qty > 5*

Comment: @NullUserException : Meh, there are a plethora of ways of creating a sequential list of numbers.  The more shuddering thought is what may be done with these results :)